# Monitoring a LiPo battery while powering the Arduino

Tags: arduino, dc-dc-converter, boost, lipo, tp4056

Well I am tring to make a circuit to charging lipo battery then use lipo. while arduino nano using lipo battery, nano measuring the voltage level of lipo. I am planning to make deep sleep if voltage level decrease to under 3.5 volt.

I have used [tp4056](https://www.robotistan.com/tp4056-type-c-1s-37v-lipo-li-ion-pil-sarj-devresi), [5v boost converter](https://www.robotistan.com/5v-600ma-usb-cikisi-voltaj-yukseltici-regulator-karti-step-up?language=tr&h=999cf91e&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7pKFBhDUARIsAFUoMDbZBikXb0jXYTUzg72qBgu1btvFpTI9qt-U6M4r0p2RYVd6Gpc4H-waApJZEALw_wcB) and [lipo battery](https://karakoyelektronik.com/li-po/px425085-81660)

everthing working fine 5v boost converter gives 5v output until If I plug in the battery + pin to NANO A0 pin. after plugin A0 pin, 5 boost converter decrease to ouput voltage near to 3 volt.

How to measeure correct voltage level of lipo battery while I am powering the arduino nano with lipo?

this is my circuit

[image]

Comment: Do you have schematics for each of those modules to know how they work?

Comment: Measure all voltages in fault condition, not just output

Comment: Is the ground passed through from the input to the output of the 3.7 to 5V converter?  If not, then you have no good ground between the Arduino and the charger.

Comment: Off topic but is this useful even if it were to work? The AVR can sleep all it wants to, that boost converter will continue to drain the battery. It probably uses more current on it's own then the entire AVR.

Comment: @SimonB even if I coneect gnd, there is no change